# Singleton implementation check

Tags: c#, singleton

Hi I am interested in implementing a method that returns an singleton object.I have created an implementation based on an example found on MSDN but I am not really sure if my implementation is corect.

The code runs just fine but I am not sure how to check if it's the same object instance.

Here is my code:

```
 public class FileShareAccessFactory : IFileShareAccessFactory
{
    private volatile static IFileShareAccess m_fileShareAccess;
    private static object m_SyncRoot = new object();

    public IFileShareAccess GetFileShareAccessInstance(IContextFactory contextFactory, ILogger logger)
    {
        if (m_fileShareAccess == null)
        {
            lock (m_SyncRoot)
            {
                if (m_fileShareAccess == null)
                {
                    m_fileShareAccess = new FileShareAccess(contextFactory, logger);
                }
            }
        }
        return m_fileShareAccess;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look on the right panel of your question

Comment: What do you mean with "how to check if it's the same object instance"?

Comment: Did you try comparing both objects using "=="? This will check for reference equality. eg. if(previousobj == newobj). This will be true if both object point to the same reference.

Comment: You must remove the outer _if (m_fileShareAccess == null)_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen no, that is not necessary at all; that works just fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As double-checked implementations go, yes - that'll work ok. It doesn't even need the `volatile`, since the synchronized double-check will deal with any small number of "it was a false `null` read". Personally, I'd be more concerned with the fact that it **doesn't seem to respect the API** - i.e. if I ask if for an instance *specifying a particular context-factory and logger*, it actually gives me something that used an **unrelated** context-factory and logger. Frankly, there are also IoC/DI containers which you could simply offload this to.

Comment: nice spot regarding external dependencies

Comment: The external dependencies will always be the same

Answer (score 0):

Use `object.ReferenceEquals()` to check if both objects are the same instance.

For example:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetFileShareAccessInstance()
    {
        var first = FileShareAccessFactory.GetFileShareAccessInstance(contextFactory, logger);
        var second = FileShareAccessFactory.GetFileShareAccessInstance(contextFactory, logger);

        Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(first, second));
    }
```

Comment: with the edit, I see what you mean now; however, that isn't really sufficient for testing code that may have threading dependencies, which singleton patterns often do

Comment: @MarcGravell, I agree this is just a basic answer.

Answer (score 0):

I now notice you have dependencies in your constructor, if this really is a singleton, then they also must be singletons. If not, then you want to think again about this as a singleton.

You may want to look at dependency injection such as Unity. This way you can register this class with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` to enforce a singleton on both the context factory, logger and this object. It allows for flexibility later where you may have more context factories thus need more `FileShareAccessFactory`s.

Other improvements you must make if you keep your code to enforce just one instance:

1. Make the constructor private.
2. Seal the class - or a descended class could be constructed.